# Subset of dense set a question about the distance from a set.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, proof-explanation, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a real Hilbert space and let $(e_k)_k$ be a orthonormal sequence in $H$. Suppose that $\text{sp}\left(e_k\;|\;k\in\mathbb{N}\right)$ is dense in $H$.

Now, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ let $M_n:=\text{sp}(e_1,\dots, e_n).$

I would like to know the reason for the following statement (I know that it comes from the hypothesis of density but I cannot understand why it can now be applied to this finite subspace $M_n$. I believe that some theoretical reason escapes me)

> For all $x\in H$ we have that $$\text{d}_{M_n}(x)\to 0,\quad\text{for}\quad n\to\infty,$$ where $\text{d}_{M_n}$ denote the distance of $x$ from $M_n.$

$\large\text{My attempt}$

We have that $$d_{M_n}(x):=\inf_{y\in M_n}\lVert x-y \rVert=\inf\left\lVert x-\sum_{k=1}^n c_ke_k\right\rVert\le \left\lVert x-\sum_{k=1}^n c_ke_k\right\rVert\quad\text{for all}\quad n\in\mathbb{N}.$$ Observe that the sequence $$\left\{ \sum_{k=1}^n c_ke_k\right\}\subseteq M_n\subseteq\text{sp}(e_k\;|\; k\in\mathbb{N})\quad\text{for all}\quad n\in\mathbb{N},$$ then, for hypothesis, we have that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left\lVert x-\sum_{k=1}^n c_ke_k\right\rVert=0$$ and so $$d_{M_n}(x)\to 0\quad\text{for}\quad n\to\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $\text{sp}\left(e_k\;|\;k\in\mathbb{N}\right)$ is dense in $H$, $\{e_1,e_2,...\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $H$. Then

$$d_{M_n}(x) = ||x- \sum_{k=1}^n(x,e_k)e_k||,$$

where $(*,* )$ denotes the inner product on $H$. By Bessel's equality we have

$$d_{M_n}(x)^2 = ||x- \sum_{k=1}^n(x,e_k)e_k||^2=||x||^2-\sum_{k=1}^n|(x,e_k)|^2.$$

Since $\{e_1,e_2,...\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $H$, we have that

$$||x||^2=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|(x,e_k)|^2.$$

This gives

$$d_{M_n}(x)\to 0,\quad\text{for}\quad n\to\infty.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But my text asserts this regardless of the orthonormal basis. So is there an alternative proof?